# Объекты и ссылки на них в JS

Tags: jquery, javascript

Не удается корректно передать значение переменной в обработчик события.

```
function createLi(params) {
    for (oneRow in params) {
        $item = $('<li />').html($('<a href="#" />').html('text').click(oneRow, params[oneRow].action));
        $('ul').append($item);
    }
}

createLi(
        [
            {
                oneProp: 'ONEPROP',
                action: function(){
                    //как здесь получить доступ к oneProp
                    console.log(oneRow); //вернет 3, а нужно 1.
                }
            },
            {

                action: function(){
                    console.log(oneRow); //вернет 3, а нужно 2.
                }
            },
            {
                action: function(){

                }
            }
        ]
);
```

Answer (score 1):

Данные, передаваемые в обработчик, хранятся в свойстве data объекта события, т.е. можно написать так: `action: function(e) { console.log(e.data) }` - и получим соотв. значение oneRow, только, т.к. это индекс, оно будет равно 0, а не 1.
См. http://jsfiddle.net/2qacm19m/

HTML

```
<ul></ul>
```

CSS

```
function createLi(params) {
    for (oneRow in params) {
        $item = $('<li />').html($('<a href="#" />').html('text').click(params[oneRow], params[oneRow].action));
        $('ul').append($item);
    }
}

$(function() {
    createLi(
        [
            {
                oneProp: 'ONEPROP',
                action: function(e){
                    //как здесь получить доступ к oneProp
                    console.log(e.data.oneProp); //вернет 3, а нужно 1.
                }
            },
            {

                action: function(){
                    console.log(oneRow); //вернет 3, а нужно 2.
                }
            },
            {
                action: function(){

                }
            }
        ]
);
})
```